# HAML Bootstrap 4 and rails - Expand accordion based on local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, haml

I have a rails app that has courses. Each course has chapters and each chapter has lessons. I am using a bootstrap accordion to show the list of chapters and lessons for the current course, but cannot figure out how to get the current chapter that the user is on to expand but leave the rest collapsed. I've tried adding the render lessons under the bottom line, tried some javascript, different levels of indentation. The accordion works but everything starts expanded.

```
  #accordion
  .list-group#scrollable
    - @chapters.each do |chapter|
      .panel.panel-default
        .list-group-item.shadow
          %a{"data-parent" => "#accordion", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "#collapse#{chapter.id}"}
            = render 'chapters/chapter_preview', chapter: chapter
      -if @lesson.chapter_id = chapter.id
        .panel-collapse.collapse.show{:id => "collapse#{chapter.id}"}
          - chapter.lessons.rank(:row_order).each do |lesson|
            .panel-body
              - if lesson.eql?(@lesson)
                %li.list-group-item.list-group-item-success
                  = render 'lessons/lesson_student', lesson: lesson
              - else
                %li.list-group-item.list-group-item-secondary
                  = render 'lessons/lesson_student', lesson: lesson
      -else
        .panel-collapse.collapse.in{:id => "collapse#{chapter.id}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a typo what could cause the issue

```rb
- if @lesson.chapter_id = chapter.id
# should be
- if @lesson.chapter_id == chapter.id
# if lesson belongs_to chapter and chapter has_many lessons you could even get rid of the id:
- if @lesson.chapter == chapter
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! This worked perfectly! I can't believe I spent 3 days trying to figure out an equal sigh -_- Thank you!